# Bind Combobox To Enum List & Change Position of Another Tables Bindingsource

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding

I have the following:

- a table of addresses and a bindingsource for the table
- a enum list of address type: 0 = "Mailing", 1 = "Physical", 2 = "Shipping" etc...

I would like to bind the datasource of the combobox to the enum so it displays "Mailing", "Physical" etc.  Then I would like to change the bindingsource position of the address table based on the user selection of the combobox.

Here is what I have so far:

```
cbxAddressName.DataSource = New BindingSource(ApplicationEnums.GetEnumList(GetType(ApplicationEnums.CompanyAddressType)), Nothing)
cbxAddressName.ValueMember = "Value"
cbxAddressName.DisplayMember = "Key"

cbxAddressName.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", bgsAddress, "AddressType", False)
```

It correctly displays the enum in the combobox but does not change the position of the bindingsource.

The table of address is as follows:

- AddressID
- AddressType
- Street
- State
- Zip
- Country

C# or VB.NET code would be great, thanks.

Comment: What are the other tables populating other combo boxes or a datagridview

Comment: The table is the address table I use the bindingsource to populate other textboxes to edit the address.

Comment: @postonoh, was that you meant?

Comment: Have you tried handling the selectedValueChanged or SelectedIndexChanged events on the combo box and using that to change your textboxes?

Comment: @D.. no I haven't yet, I thought it would be better to bind directly. Do I have it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your table will contain at most one address for each of the enum values. That is, zero or one Mailing, zero or one Physical, zero or one Shipping etc.

There's no need to create a DataBinding (nor would it work). There's also no need to create a datasource for the combo box. Just use the same BindingSource for both the table and the combo box, and they will automatically be synchronized.

```
public class Address
{
    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public enum AddressType
{
    Business,
    Home,
    Other,
    PostOfficBox,
}
```

To demo this, add a ComboBox and a BindingSource to the form, set the BingingSource datasource to the Address type, and add a TextBox and bind it to the Street property of the BindingSource.
Then put this code in the Form1 constructor:

```
{
    var addresses = new List<Address> {
        new Address { AddressType = AddressType.Business, Street = "123 Commercial Ave" },
        new Address { AddressType = AddressType.Home, Street = "456 Suburbia Lane" },
        new Address { AddressType = AddressType.Other, Street = "789 Booty Blvd" },
        new Address { AddressType = AddressType.PostOfficBox, Street = "PO BOX 1000" },
    };

    tableBindingSource.DataSource = addresses; 

    comboBox1.DataSource = tableBindingSource;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "AddressType";
}
```

The combobox will call ToString() on the AddressType, so what you see will be the names of the enum values. If you want to see a different value (e.g. "PO Box" instead of "PostOfficeBox"), there's a little bit more to do. I know I've written an answer about that before so I won't repeat it here (ask me or search my answers if you want that).

Selecting an item in the combobox will change the Current item of its BindingSource, and any other controls bound to that BindingSource will be updated.